# Unable to edit inline with phpMyAdmin even though table contains a unique/primary key

Tags: phpmyadmin

I can never edit (either inline or by clicking the edit button) a row in my database through phpMyAdmin (version 4.5.5.1) due to the error "This table does not contain a unique column. Features related to the grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete links may not work after saving." with the SQL showing as having an empty "WHERE" clause. I've gone through and double checked that I do in fact have primary keys and even added an additional 'Unique' key but I still get the error.

I'm actually getting this error on every table I have in this specific database, **HOWEVER**, if I copy over a table from a different database from a different site using phpMyAdmin (version 4.5.3.1) using the export function, I can then get it to work!!! Is there something I'm missing when creating tables from scratch in phpMyAdmin?

Exported structure of a table:

```
CREATE TABLE 'userAccessLevel' (
  'userAccessLevelID' int(11) NOT NULL,
  'userAccessLevel' varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  'description' text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  'title' varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE 'userAccessLevel'
  ADD PRIMARY KEY ('userAccessLevelID'),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY 'userAccessLevelID' ('userAccessLevelID');

ALTER TABLE 'userAccessLevel'
  MODIFY 'userAccessLevelID' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: Your export works for me with 4.5.5.1 (after I adjust all the single-quote ' characters to backticks ` ). If you use the phpMyAdmin copy feature (from the Operations tab) to copy that table to a new name or another database, are you still unable to edit?

Comment: Yes, using the copy table from the operations tab still leaves me unable to edit lines.

Comment: This appears to be a problem with table starting with (or containing?) uppercase letters. Try checking out http://www.ryadel.com/en/configure-mysql-handle-camel-case-case-sensitive-table-names/ However, having provided `lower_case_table_names = 2` in `my.ini` does not resolve the issue.

Comment: @Kafoso So this does seem to be the case that the issue is actually only in tables that contain an uppercase character. I also tried the setting you referenced and it did not work for me either. Something else I noticed, the uppercase letter causing trouble appears to only be happening on systems where the initial version of phpMyAdmin included the ability to do inline editing. On my other system that started off on an older version but just recently got updated, I am able to do inline editing on tables with an uppercase character in the table name.

Comment: @user1857842 I ended up downgrading to version 4.4.14.1, because the issue has not yet been resolved. See: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11816#issuecomment-211868859

Comment: Thanks! I'll be able to downgrade at least one environment.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use all lowercase letters in the table name.  Copy the table if it already exists to a temporary name, delete the old table and then rename the new table to the old name.

This most likely and most often happens on Windows because the *lower_case_table_names* setting conflicts with the OS settings (Windows is case-insensitive).

You can set *lower_case_table_names* but, according to the [authoritative site](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html):

> lower_case_table_names can **only be configured when initializing the
>   server**. Changing the lower_case_table_names setting after the server
>   is initialized is prohibited.